# GridView Events are not Firing in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a Gridview but the events are not firing?

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" DataKeyNames="Ac_Code" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" Width="100%" BorderStyle="Solid" style="overflow:auto" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView3_SelectedIndexChanged"  OnRowDataBound="GridView3_RowDataBound" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="GridView3_Sorting" OnRowCreated="GridView3_RowCreated">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCFF" />
                    <Columns>                      
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Ac_Code" HeaderText="A/c Code" SortExpression="Ac_Code" ItemStyle-Width="12%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Dth" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Ac_Name" HeaderText="Account" SortExpression="Ac_Name" ItemStyle-Width="12%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Dth"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Ac_Sub_Group_Name" HeaderText="A/c Sub Group" SortExpression="Ac_Sub_Group_Name" ItemStyle-Width="12%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Dth" />
                        <asp:CommandField SelectText="Select" ShowSelectButton="true" Visible="false" />
                    </Columns>

                </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: When are you binding your grid to the DataSource, only if(!Postback)?

Comment: How do you conclude that it is not firing? Which event is not firing? You need to share the code of event handlers too.

Comment: it would be helpful if you can share code of datasource assign and event handlers..

Comment: Selected Indexchanged event is  not firing...   protected void GridView3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                AcCodeName = GridView3.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
                txtSupplier.Text = AcCodeName;
                txtSuppQtnNo.Focus();
            }
            catch
            {
                ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

You must not bind your grid on postbacks in Page_Load, only when something changed that causes the Grid to reload data(f.e. Sorting,Paging) and only in the appropriate event-handlers.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        grid.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Another possible reasons: 
    a. Have you disabled ViewState somewhere? 
    b. onrowcommand= attribute not being set in the asp:GridView element. This should be set to the name of the handler which will be handling the event.

Comment: The OP posted code that's using declarative event-handlers. Manual binding is unnecessary.

Comment: I bind the grid on postback in pageload

Comment: can you put the databind without postback..see my answer edited above

Comment: can u put "AutoPostBack = true"